# Regex expression used to list all the files except some is showing error in bash

Tags: bash, glob

`ls -al charts/**/*[^values,^Chart].yaml`

The above command is supposed to list all the yaml files inside charts folder except values.yaml and chart.yaml.

When I try this command in mac it works fine but not in bash i.e linux terminal. Is there any way to do the same in bash?

Comment: You can't use regular expressions in filename expansion. bash has a regular expression test operator ( `=~`), but to use it in your case, you would first have to create an array of all filenames and loop over the array and test each array element individually. BTW, your string (in particular the `**` part) wouldn't be a regular expression anyway. Note that an `*` in a regexp means _zero or more occurances of the previous item_. I think you are referring to _globbing_ here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` for it:

```sh
find charts/ \! -name values.yaml -a \! -name Chart.yaml
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is working fine but I am using datree to validate all the files in the gitlab pipeline... thats y I tried ls which will return me the list

Comment: helm datree test charts/**/*[^values,^Chart].yaml this is my script... when I use the same in mac. its working but not in bash and gitlab also uses bash I guess.. thats why the pipeline is also failing

Comment: and also I need just the yaml files.. it is listing all the files

Comment: @PujaSingh Adding `-name '*.yaml'` will give you just the `.yaml` files.

Answer (score 0):

`Zsh` in MacOS and `bash` have different syntax. Would you please try:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
ls -al charts/**/!(*values|*Chart).yaml
```

The `shopt` command in the 1st line enables the extended pattern matching option in bash. You can put the command in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "regular expression", you say `grep` :-)

I would advise you the following:

```
find charts/ -name "*.yaml" | grep -v "values.yaml" | grep -v "chart.yaml"
```

The `-v` switch filters out the results.